# Does the deleting of resource group in Azure deallocates and deletes everything that is inside that resource group?

Tags: azure

I need to delete all resources in a resource group. If I delete a resource group, will Azure deallocates and deletes everything that is in that resource group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, deleting a resource group will delete all child services. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/delete-resource-group)